# Adding attributes to a feature using ChangeAttributeValues in Pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, qgis-3

I have a `workareas` polygon layer with `X` number of features and a `buffer` CSV layer with `Y` number of entries which looks like the table below (one `id` field and a couple other fields).

```
id1  | A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1
id2  | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2
id3  | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3
id4  | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4
id5  | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5
```

What I want to achieve is to duplicate every `workarea` feature `Y` times and copy the CSV table attributes. I've pasted my code below, but the `changeAttributeValues` does not work for me.

```
workareas_mem = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs="+workarea_lyr.sourceCrs().authid(), 'polygon', 'memory')
prov = workareas_mem.dataProvider()
prov.addAttributes([field for field in workarea_lyr.fields()])
prov.addAttributes([field for field in buffer_tbl.fields()])
fld_names = [field.name() for field in buffer_tbl.fields()]
workareas_mem.updateFields()

if True:
    for i, workarea in enumerate(workarea_lyr.getFeatures()):
        for buffer in buffer_tbl.getFeatures():
            new_feat = workarea
            prov.addFeatures([new_feat])
            for fld in fld_names:
                prov.changeAttributeValues({new_feat.id():{prov.fieldNameMap()[fld]:buffer[fld]}})
        feedback.setProgress(int(i* total))
```

The code successfully creates the duplicate `workarea` features and I end up with `X*Y` features in total. But the attributes from the CSV table does not write properly. Attached below is a sample output from this code.

[image]

Comment: are you calling  `commitChanges` after `changeAttributeValues`?